# DotNetOpenAuth + classic ASP + oAuth

Tags: asp-classic, oauth, dotnetopenauth

I am trying to get dotNetOpenAuth to work with facebook and twitter.  There are some great examples provided but I am stuck using classic asp.  I have the sample that uses classic asp and openID working fine.

Is it possible to use oAuth & dotNetOpenAuth & classic asp?  If so, is there an example somewhere that I can reference?

thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in support for OAuth on Classic ASP in DotNetOpenAuth, although you can certainly add it yourself by simply writing a .NET COM server .dll that acts as the go-between between classic ASP and DotNetOpenAuth (which is how DotNetOpenAuth itself makes it work for OpenID).

You should realize that Facebook uses OAuth 2.0 while Twitter uses OAuth 1.0.  OAuth 2.0 clients are very easy to write, even without a library at all, so you can probably get away without this work.  But Twitter does require some serious code on the client (aka consumer) side so if you want that, you'll likely need to shim a .NET library such as DotNetOpenAuth to help you.